# FFMPEG is zoompan works on first and last only

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert images to video which works fine with ffmpeg but i need to add ken burns effect to every images.

the code i was to get only only works on the last and first images (the effect i mean).

```
ffmpeg -y -i %d.jpg -t 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf zoompan=z='zoom+0.001':s=1280x800,scale=hd1080 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 22 -t 300 -threads 2  zoomout.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

the problem is from the images, so i used new set of images